# ROS Answers SE migration: Losing TFs

Tags: transforms, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is my problem with TFs:

- I have a node publishing a topic and its related TF:

> pose_tf = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
> o = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(roll, pitch, yaw, 'sxyz')
> pose_tf.sendTransform((pose_x, pose_y, pose_z),
> o,
> topic.header.stamp,
> topic.header.frame_id,
> main_frame)
> self.pub.publish(topic)

- From another node, I subscribe to this topic using

> rospy.Subscriber("/topic_name", TopicType, self.function)

- Each time this node receives a */topic_name*, function *self.function* is executed. To obtain the TF relating the *main_frame* and the *topic_frame* I use:

> try:
>     (trans, rot) = self.listener.lookupTransform(
> main_frame,
> topic.header.frame_id,
> topic.header.stamp)
> except (tf.LookupException,
> tf.ConnectivityException,
> tf.ExtrapolationException):
>     rospy.logerr('Define TF for the topic!)

- For the first messages the *lookupTransform* function always generates an exception. After 1 second it starts working properly. I've tried adding a *waitForTransform* but I've the same problem.

> self.listener.waitForTransform(main_frame, topic.header.frame_id, rospy.Time(), rospy.Duration(4.0))

Is it correct to put in the *lookupTransform* the time *topic.header.stamp* instead of *rospy.Time(0)*? (I d'ont want the last TF but the one published in this moment). Am I using function *waitForTransform* correctly? Any idea?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and ros fuerte. Thank you!

UPDATE:
If I add the *waitForTransform* call inside the try-exception block I can see the following (where line 277 corresponds to *self.listener.waitForTransform(main_frame, topic.header.frame_id, rospy.Time(), rospy.Duration(1.0))*):

> bad callback: <bound method PoseEkfSlam.landmarkUpdate of <**main**.PoseEkfSlam instance at 0xab3f6cc>>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 678, in _invoke_callback
> cb(msg)
> File "/home/narcis/workspace/cola2/pose_ekf_slam/src/pose_ekf_slam.py", line 277, in landmarkUpdate
> rospy.Duration(1.0))
> Exception

Seems that *waitForTransform* or maybe *rospy.Duration(1.0)* are generating and exception.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47167/losing-tfs/) by [narcispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1214/narcispr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-31**:
Which exception do you get?

**Comment by [narcispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1214/narcispr/) on 2012-10-31**:
Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame "frame_name"

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-31**:
Could you maybe post the source code that is causing the error? The callback seems to raise an error somewhere and it would be interesting what the exception is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code looks correct. It just takes a while until the TF tree evolves completely and that's where your error within the first second probably comes from. I think it is definitely possible to get exceptions during that time. However, I don't feel like waitForTransform should really throw an exception here. I'm not sure if this is a bug or an actual design decision but you might want to consider filing a ticket at the [corresponding bug tracker](https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/trac).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3